# Choosing between JDBC or ADO.NET, performance studies on Oracle

Tags: oracle, ado.net, jdbc

We are starting a new project, which talks to an Oracle database with millions of data. The system is mission critical and should be highly performant. We are now choosing the technologies that will be involved in the system, and we are doubting between JDBC or ADO.NET for data access.

Which technology is most performant? Are there any studies that test both technologies with Oracle database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either JDBC or ADO.NET works just fine. Oracle's JDBC drivers are really good; so are the ADO.NET drivers.  Do your best to obtain the latest driver versions that are compatible with your server.  Your choice (JDBC/ADO.NET) should be dictated by the implementation technology of the rest of your client software.  If you're building a dot Net (in a Visual Studio environment) app use ADO.NET.  If you're building a Java client (e.g. in Eclipse) use JDBC.

Where you will run into performance trouble is if you try to build a heterogeneous client, trying to use software gaffer tape to attach JDBC to a C++ program, or ADO.NET to a Java program.  That will be slower and more unstable.  For example Crystal Reports claims to be able to use JDBC data connectors, but they have an inefficient adapter between their native code and Java.

Comment: I totally agree, however the client is requesting us performances test to complete our reasoning, even if those documents say that both are equal in perfomance terms. I haven't found anything that compares performance between ado.net and jdbc

Answer (score 1):

I feel like the bulk of your time in a query is going to be spent waiting on Oracle, I have a hard time believing your API of choice is going to be the bottleneck you will care about in the long haul.  Besides, isn't this a function of your development environment way more than it is of performance?